# UITableViewController weird behavior after popping a view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, scroll

My `UITableView` has a bunch of reusable cells, and when I tap on one of them, it takes me to another view controller (via push segue) showing the details of that cell (let's say it's an item, so it would show details about an item - name, price, image, etc...). When I pop that view controller (by tapping on the back button), the `UITableView` has a strange behavior:

a) if it's scrolled all the way to the bottom, it will scroll automatically tad up (around 50 points), leaving the last cell barely visible, so I have to scroll back down again. My cell  all have 60 points for height.

b) the scrollbar always shows and then disappears, indicating that something is moving that `UITableView` (although if not scrolled to the bottom, the content will not move automatically).

This happens in multiple `UITableView`'s I have in my app. I am not forcing a reload of the table view in viewWillAppear, so I don't understand what is happening. My content is static after loading from the server (unless the user changes it, and then the reload is executed). But simply showing details of an item and popping that VC doesn't change anything in the table view.

Edit: Okay, I've figured what the problem is: I'm hiding a `UIToolbar` when pushing that segue. If I keep it always visible (which I don't want), it still shows the scrollbars animating when popping in my table view but doesn't scroll the table view if on the last few rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to fix the first issue. It seems like the tableview is not taking into account the 44 points of the `UIToolbar`.

Save the tableview offset in `prepareForSegue:` (save it in a `CGPoint` property)

```
self.tableViewScrollOffset = self.tableView.contentOffset;
```

Then, in `viewWillAppear:`, check if it has been modified. If so, restore it.

```
if(self.tableView.contentOffset.y != self.tableViewScrollOffset.y) {
        [self.tableView setContentOffset:self.tableViewScrollOffset];
        self.tableViewScrollOffset = CGPointZero;
    }
```

Comment: Could you explain in more detail why this is happening? Or could someone.

Comment: Its amazing...solved the similar issue...The problem is that, whenever you navigate back from a viewcontroller , the tableview scroll offset changes accordingly.                                                                                   So you need to capture the contentoffset value in a property  inside prePareForSegue: method (i.e, before navigating) and then check that in the same class inside viewWillAppear: method . And if it is changed then set the scrolloffset property value to zero

Answer (score 7):

Add the following to viewDidLoad.

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;
```

This solved my problem of table view moving down after navigating back to view controller.

Answer (score 3):

This behavior is indeed a bug in iOS 8.x.

All answers given so far can not really solve the issue. The issue is, that iOS forgets (or doesn't) consider the previously calculated cell sizes, when a table is being redrawn for instance when the view is being pushed.

One approach to solve this can be found here: [UITableView layout messing up on push segue and return. (iOS 8, Xcode beta 5, Swift)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25221031) (so this question is even a duplicate to this one).

However, the solution provided there is overkill and there are certain situations why this caching will fail (for instance a UIContentSizeCategoryDidChangeNotification is not regarded)

But there is a quite simpler solution even though it is odd:

If you are using a manual `performSequeWithIdentifier` in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, just add a `[self.tableView reloadData]` just before.

If you are using a IB seque from the cell, just add `[self.tableView reloadData]` in your `prepareForSeque` code.

The reason, why this solves the issue is, that this will force iOS to re-estimate the visible cells and so it no longer scrolls the content to another location. Fortunately, `tableView reloadData` doesn't cost too much overhead here as only the visible cells will be re-estimated.

Answer (score 0):

Just a hunch, have you got a rogue `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated` hanging around?

Comment: Nope, I searched my entire project for that in Xcode and no code lines pop up.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing this issue. I managed to find it out. The reason in my case is tableview header height was calculating based text and text height was negative due to which tableview was shifting down even though the contentinset and scrollinset are zero.

This was only occurring for first time. Next time it is calculating correct. One weired thing i found is that when Class A (having tableview) have pushed another Class B from init. When keyboard from Class B is opened viewDidLoad of Class A is called. and before Class B is unloaded from navigation controller. Tableview is reloaded for Class A.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets as suggested above did not work neither did caching and setting the tableViewScrollOffset work.

Hence came up with an workaround which worked like a charm for me.

The workaround was to add an Dummy UIView which has height of 1px and width of 320px and place it between the "Top Layout Guide" and the UITableView. This view's background could be set to clear so that it is invisible.

Now using Autolayouts, fix the Dummy View's top to the Top. Now set the tableview's top constraint with respect to Dummy View. Found that this resolved the issue of the tableview's misplacement.

Screenshot of the Dummy View along with the autolayout constraints have been provided for easy reference. The Dummy View has been set to a larger height and red background colour for illustration purpose only.

[image]