# IOS 8 tableview reloads automatically when pop out of view

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, ios8

I have developed my project in `IOS Base SDK 7.1`, Now i am running `ios 7.1` no issues while the time pop out of view, the same project running `IOS 8` while the time of pop out view automatically table reloading.

Please guide this
Thanks in advance
S.Arul

Comment: Any one look this issue.

Comment: I am also having the same issue .Please let me know if you solve this issue.

Comment: What does "while the time pop out of view" means?

Comment: while dismissing view controller

Comment: possible duplicate of [ios 8 tableview reloads automatically when view appears after pop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27717285/ios-8-tableview-reloads-automatically-when-view-appears-after-pop) -- I myself have the same problem: https://github.com/cyrille-legrand/ios8-tableview-autoreload